# Removing '+' from a Query String

Tags: javascript, string

I have scoured the Internet for an answer to this.  I have an array of strings that looks something like this:

```
[0] Cinnamon+Chocolate+Twists
[1] 3.25+Ounce+Croissant
```

I need all the '+' characters removed from these strings, and a space inserted instead. The following code does not work:

```
nameProduct[1] = nameProduct[1].replace("+"," ");
```

I have tried several variations of the .replace method, but no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: The code you posted *does* work (single quotes) - sorry, this is wrong.

Comment: Actually, no it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/2pdXY/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use regular expression with the `g`lobal flag to replace every occurrence of the character (*yes, JavaScript behaves weird in this aspect (or let's say unexpected, depending from which other language you come)*):

```
nameProduct[1] = nameProduct[1].replace(/\+/g," ");
```

Use a loop to do this for every element.

*[MDC - `replace` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)*

---

**Update:**

Don't use `document.write` to create HTML. [Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/2pdXY/3/) needs a lot of refactoring but this beyond this question. The data is processed correctly, but the generated HTML is not:

```
<input type="text" size="40" name="Product1401" value="Cinnamon" chocolate="" twists="" readonly="">
```

You see, you have problems with the quotes. The other parts of the text are recognized as attributes.

A slightly improved version would be (just this part):

```
var nameProduct = hashes[i].split('=');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var td = document.createElement('td');
var input = document.createElement('input');

input.type = "text";
input.size = 40;
input.name = nameProduct[0]      
nameProduct[1] = nameProduct[1].replace(/%/g, '');
nameProduct[1] = nameProduct[1].replace(/2C/g, '');
nameProduct[1] = nameProduct[1].replace(/2F/g, '');
nameProduct[1] = nameProduct[1].replace(/28/g, '');
nameProduct[1] = nameProduct[1].replace(/29/g, '');
nameProduct[1] = nameProduct[1].replace(/\+/g, " ");

input.value = nameProduct[1];
input.readOnly = true;

td.appendChild(input);
tr.appendChild(td);
document.getElementById('gradient-style').tBodies[0].appendChild(tr);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2pdXY/5/)

Comment: Felix: thanks a lot for answering. I tried your .replace string and it took care of all the + signs.  However, it only returned the first word in the string.  For example, instead of Cinnamon Chocolate Twists, it only returned Cinnamon.

Comment: @Sterve: Then you must do something else wrong or the string is not what you think it is. Have a look at @mellamokb's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2pdXY/ Post your the code you use.

Comment: I haven't used fiddle before, but I put my code in there (hopefully I did it right).  As you can tell, I'm extracting several items from a URL and am putting it into an HTML table.  The URL looks something like this: http://www.euroclassicpastries.com/2011/checkout.php?Product1401=Cinnamon+Chocolate+Twists&Item=1401&Weight1401=9.00&Price1401=19.66&Quantity1401=136&ExtPrice1401=2673.76&TotalWt1401=1224.00

Comment: Felix:  thanks for helping out with my rather unorthadox code. I'll give this a shot and see what happens.

Comment: @Sterve: You're welcome. I created a small example so you can see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/2pdXY/5/ But note: Also this code is far from perfect (but it should give you a start).